# JS syntaxError - chrome - Array destructuring

Tags: javascript

Following code is working fine on firefox but throwing an error on chrome - `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

I'm expecting this code to append date in given div.

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var classes = ['history', 'biology', 'physics'];
var students = 90; 

function getExamDate() {
  return [20, ' March ', 2013, ' 9AM'];
}

var [date, month, year, time] = getExamDate();

output.innerHTML(date + month + year + time);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WKdRJ/1/)

You are using `ECMAScript 6` feature called `Array destructuring` which is not a standard yet. Only modern browsers like chrome and firefox have implemented some of the features. Array destructuring is useful shorthand when returning multiple values from a function, as we do not need to wrap around an object anymore.

In your case you can tweak your code to return a simple array instead, as shown below in following code snippet.

I have used `isNumber` function to check if array item is number. If it's a string then remove quotes around it. You will end you with exactly same output.

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var classes = ['history', 'biology', 'physics'];
var students = 90; 

function getExamDate() {
  return [20, ' March ', 2013, ' 9AM'];
}

var temp = getExamDate();

for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    var str = temp[i];

    if(!isNumber(str)) {
       str = str.replace(/"/g, '');
    }

    console.log(str);
} 

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: I have read your code 5 times and still didn't get the point of `str.replace` and everything around that...

Comment: Chrome does not sport array de-structuring in the stable build yet.

Comment: @VisioN: str.replace is to provide OP exact same output as using destructuring.

Comment: Thanks, your example does exactly what I want to achieve. Works in all browsers I tested in. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

This kind of statement

```
var [date, month, year, time] = getExamDate();
```

is a [destructuring assignment](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation). It is part of ECMAScript 6. It's not yet available in most browsers.

For now, you'd better avoid assigning all those variables :

```
output.innerHTML = getExamDate().join('');
```

(yes, you had another error: `innerHTML` is accessed as a property, not a function)

[Here's a good introductory article on destructuring assignments](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/50/).

Comment: @VisioN not using innerHTML would change the _meaning_ of OP's code. That said, I completely agree something like `.textContent` is better.

Comment: Another option is transpiling with an ES6 to ES5 transpiler, but I wouldn't do it if destructuring is the only reason to do so http://traceur-compiler.googlecode.com/git/demo/repl.html#function%20getExamDate()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%5B20%2C%20'%20March%20'%2C%202013%2C%20'%209AM'%5D%3B%0A%7D%0Avar%20%5Bdate%2C%20month%2C%20year%2C%20time%5D%20%3D%20getExamDate()%3B%0A